# Meteor reactivity: Disable input while DOM updates

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is the best way to deactivate user input (e.g. form elements like `<select>`, `<input>`,  etc.) when the DOM is currently reactively updating.
This can be important when a already processing and relatively slow DOM update may be removing the input element. If you are allowed to interact with it while it is not yet removed, the application may get into a bad state.

Although this is hopefully a reasonable question, for those who care: The slow DOM update comes mostly from a Mini-Mongo operation on a rather large dataset and big DOM update.

Comment: Do you have a replication of the issue? or some code perhaps?

Comment: Sorry no; there are many files involved and I cannot share it all. Mabe it helps if you know that we are talking about a table with several columns and many rows. There is a dropdown for each column and it lets you filter certain values. So if one filter changes, the options available in other dropdowns will change too. Now while one filter change is rendering, I am looking for a way to disable all other dropdowns until the current DOM update finished (and thus all filter values are up-to-date).

Comment: Are you changing the filter via a subscription? a pub/sub pattern? or are you just simply hooking template events to a collection?

Comment: The subscription is not changed. Only the query in Mini-Mongo is adjusted to use current filters.

Comment: I guess it would work with a reactive "disabled" flag per dropdown. But since Template.rendered isn't firing anymore after each render, I do not know how/when to disabled=false...